# Entity Framework nested entity not initialized

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In Entity framework a nested entity `Commandes` is not initialized in a `Client` class when used in `DbContext` but it is when inside another `DbSet`

[image: Issue]

- Here in my `Clients` list **1)** my 2nd `Client` has no `Commande`
  **2)**.
- But in my `Commandes` list **3)** my 1st `Commande` **4)** has a `Client` that has `Commande` **5)**!

They are the same `Client` in the Database! It's not the same entity with this problem... Is there a reason to this? Is there a workaround to this problem?

---

**EDIT:** It seems that depending on the order i watch this the result is different:

[image: Issue2]

---

**EDIT2:** i use the `DbContext` with dependency injection as the following:

```
public class LicencesService
{
    private VdsysDbContext vdsysDbContext;
    
    public LicencesService(VdsysDbContext dbContext)
    {
        vdsysDbContext = dbContext;
        commandeArticles = vdsysDbContext.CommandeArticles;
    }
}
```

My break point was on the line `commandeArticles = vdsysDbContext.CommandeArticles;` as i inspected the variable `vdsysDbContext`

Comment: You need to use an Instance of the class that contains the data.

Comment: @jdweng What do you mean? How should i instantiate it?

Comment: Your code has a definition "DbContent db"  The instance is db the static class is DbContent.  You are accessing static class which does not contain any data instead of the instance of the class.

Comment: @jdweng I use the DbContext by dependency injection has i always done but never had this issue (see my edit)

Comment: Not sure if this is the case for you but efcore does not lazyload related data and you need to include them using the `Include` method.

Comment: @V.S Thank you finally a Workaround! I found that i can use "Eagerly Loading"... (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data) But still i want to do lazy loading... Will continue to search for this.... You can post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help in the comments @V.S

I was sure that Entity Framework was doing **Lazy Loading** by default... Which is not the case.

So there is two solution:

The best one is to use **Eagerly Loading** (See [Loading Related Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data)). So i replaced this line:

```
commandeArticles = vdsysDbContext.CommandeArticles;
```

By

```
commandeArticles = vdsysDbContext.CommandeArticles.Include(x => x.Article).ToList();
```

Or by enabling [Lazy Loading of Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy)

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder
        .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
        .UseSqlServer(myConnectionString);
```